# Scraping from frames, POST request not working in Python

Tags: python, http, iframe, python-requests

I'm working on a project to scrape prices from a parts catalog. Since it's using frames, I've been using Chrome dev tools to see what's getting sent to the server.

I've found the request that's grabbing the data, but I can't seem to get it to work in python. I also tried making the request using Postman by copying the cURL data, but it also doesn't work.

This is the code I'm using:

```
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "Cache-control": "no-cache,no-store",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "205",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Cookie": "COOKIE HERE",
    "Expires": "0",
    "Host": "partscatalog.deere.com",
    "Origin": "https://partscatalog.deere.com",
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "Referer": "https://partscatalog.deere.com/jdrc/navigation/equipment/69779",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36",
    "X-TS-AJAX-Request": "true"
}

payload = {'{"eq":"69779","fr":{"businessRegion":1061,"filtersEnabled":"true","encodedFilters":null,"filteringLevel":null,"currentPin":null,"equipmentRefId":"69779"},"sp":"","br":"1061","locale":"en-US","vm":"p","ln":1}'}

r = requests.post("https://partscatalog.deere.com/jdrc-services/v1/navigation/p/getChildren", headers=headers, data=payload)
print(r.content)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: sometimes you have to first GET normal page to get fresh cookies and session ID.

Comment: if you send `application/json` then you may have to use `json=` instead of `data=`

Comment: @furas Special thanks furas as this was one of the main issues, I also had to make changes to the payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems with your code, first of all I would recommend your replacing your header with this one:

```
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Cookie": "COOKIE HERE",
    "Referer": "https://partscatalog.deere.com/jdrc/navigation/equipment/69779",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36",
    "X-TS-AJAX-Request": "true"
}
```

Then I would also recommend replacing this:

```
r = requests.post("https://partscatalog.deere.com/jdrc-services/v1/navigation/p/getChildren", headers=headers, data=payload)
```

with:

```
r = requests.post("https://partscatalog.deere.com/jdrc-services/v1/navigation/p/getChildren", headers=headers, json=payload)
```

hope this works

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked, but I had to make 1 more change. I was treating the null in the payload as a string, but I had to set it to Pythons equivalent of null, None.I also had to make the values for the keys "ln" and "businessRegion" integers rather than strings.